# Identifying important variables in a PLSDA model using caret in R: are coefficients standardized?

Tags: r, r-caret, coefficients

I am doing a PLSDA using the caret package in R. My objective is to predict a status of a dairy cow (0 vs 1) using milk mid-infrared spectra. I want to compare the coefficients to know which spectral points contribute the most to the prediction. If my data are centered and scaled (standardization) using the option "peProc" in caret, are the coefficients standardised or are they de-standardized? Should I use standardized or unstandardized coefficients to identify important variables?

Here is my code in R:

```
# sample of data: 10 rows and 11 columns (cow status and 10 spectral points)

data<-structure(list(status = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), X67 = c(0.0621632561087608, 0.0607260726392266, 0.0625290125608445, 
0.0630319677293305, 0.0647925734519963, 0.0652132406830785, 0.0642152130603786, 
0.0632935389876363, 0.0630211532115932, 0.0653552338480952), 
    X69 = c(0.0412880629301071, 0.0411925278604031, 0.0422371216118336, 
    0.0428165234625339, 0.0449542962014675, 0.0450734049081802, 
    0.0436325967311859, 0.0429527163505555, 0.0416706018149853, 
    0.0443116500973701), X80 = c(-0.0138179995119572, -0.0144830904901028, 
    -0.0144161432981491, -0.013074841350317, -0.0167389884591103, 
    -0.0159232392907143, -0.0143161900341511, -0.0138954184949399, 
    -0.0147733353078366, -0.0134175941348076), X81 = c(-0.0134893320500851, 
    -0.0142031051218509, -0.0142825171351433, -0.0127705596387386, 
    -0.0168376825749874, -0.0157066956162453, -0.0140237100422382, 
    -0.0135413259267807, -0.0144432000815868, -0.0128327533602714
    ), X82 = c(-0.0121541880071164, -0.0126882530748845, -0.0128774531185627, 
    -0.0113642327487468, -0.0153397060930729, -0.0141194649040699, 
    -0.012583240866661, -0.0119865834712983, -0.0129532031714916, 
    -0.0113681443035603), X83 = c(-0.0100522302091122, -0.0100194588303566, 
    -0.0103428065776825, -0.0090412348508835, -0.012253813445568, 
    -0.0112871341407299, -0.01005644723773, -0.00953329727053641, 
    -0.0103608369827271, -0.0091012343764305), X84 = c(-0.0068778395652771, 
    -0.006202656775713, -0.0066996179521084, -0.0058559291064739, 
    -0.0077349841594696, -0.0070663541555404, -0.00633592158555989, 
    -0.0060042813420295, -0.0066741779446602, -0.0058899037539959
    ), X85 = c(-0.0028718337416649, -0.0016290470957756, -0.0022227615118026, 
    -0.0018559470772744, -0.00229159742593769, -0.00200331956148141, 
    -0.0016555078327656, -0.0015552900731563, -0.0021986812353134, 
    -0.00184135138988499), X86 = c(0.001129399985075, 0.0027880594134331, 
    0.002091933041811, 0.0021506287157535, 0.0029507651925087, 
    0.00285872071981429, 0.00294967368245119, 0.0027530193328858, 
    0.0021884441375732, 0.0023270919919014), X87 = c(0.0043732412159443, 
    0.0061031468212605, 0.0052727945148945, 0.0052438415586949, 
    0.00681021064519879, 0.0065649412572384, 0.0064241252839565, 
    0.00608809292316441, 0.0055649057030678, 0.0056490488350391
    )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")



Ycalib<-factor(data[,1],levels=c("1","0"),labels=c("status_1","status_2"))
names(Ycalib)<-c("y")
Xcalib<-data.frame(data[,2:11])


set.seed(1001)
folds<-createFolds(Ycalib,k=10,list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)

set.seed(1001) 
ctrl<-trainControl(method="repeatedcv",index=folds,classProbs = TRUE,summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,savePredictions = TRUE)

set.seed(1001)
plsda<-train(x=Xcalib, # spectral data
             y=Ycalib, # factor vector
             method="pls", # pls-da algorithm
             tuneLength=20, # number of components
             trControl=ctrl, # ctrl contained cross-validation option
             preProc=c("center","scale"), # the data are centered and scaled
             metric="ROC") # metric is ROC for 2 classes

coefficients<-coef(plsda$finalModel)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data with `dput`? Also since, it's more about the statistics surrounding pre-processing, I would suggest asking over at Cross Validated.

Comment: Thank you. I provided a sample of my data using dput (I hope it is enough, I am a beginner with R and on Stackoverflow). What do you mean by "asking over at Cross Validated"?

Comment: Cross Validated is part of the StackExchange network specifically for statistics related questions. It can be found [here](stats.stackexchange.com).